# What will be the exact X-Path to fetch the value in WSO2?

Tags: properties, wso2, mediator

I have made an api to insert values in a table by `wso2` (which is working)

But I'm also getting an error message as below:

> java.sql.SQLException: Communication link failure

So I want to store this error message in a property.

Which `xpath` I have to use to store this error message that will be also seen while invoking the rest service by postman ?

I want that user also get this error message like below:

```
{
  "Result": "java.sql.SQLException: Communication link failure."
}
```

Comment: You should give more details.

Answer (score 1):

Within the fault sequence, you can access these property values using the get-property XPath function.

```
<property name="Fault_Message" expression="get-property('ERROR_MESSAGE')"/>
```

Fault sequence

```
<faultSequence>
      <property expression="get-property('ERROR_CODE')"
        name="ERROR_CODE" scope="default" type="STRING"/>
      <property expression="get-property('ERROR_MESSAGE')"
        name="ERROR_MESSAGE" scope="default" type="STRING"/>
    </faultSequence>
```

You can find more information here

https://docs.wso2.com/display/ESB460/Error+Handling+and+Error+Codes